# What was being filmed at Frederiksborg Castle on 5 August 2020?

Tags: film-location

We visited [Frederiksborg Castle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederiksborg_Castle) (Hillerød, Denmark) on 5 August 2020.

While we there, filming was taking place in the [inner courtyard](https://www.kevmrc.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/frederiksborg-castle-inner-courtyard.jpeg). What was this filming for?

There was quite a large number of people dressed up (perhaps 20+) in black tie and fancy dresses. It gave the impression of a (fictional) fancy event, e.g. a Hollywood premiere. I think there was a red carpet involved.

It was unclear if the filming was for a TV show, film, or advert of some kind.

The castle's English lamguage Wikipedia page has a "Cultural references" section, but the only release after 2020 mentioned is Le Casa de papel and [a description of scenes from that TV show](https://money-heist.fandom.com/wiki/Frederiksborg_Castle) don't seem to fit the filming we saw.

Danish language Wikipedia has no such section. IMDB mentions some productions with this filming location but they are from before 2020.

What was being filmed while we were there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Netflix tv series La Casa De Papel (Money Heist) was filming there when you were visiting.

Wikipedia entry for the castle says:

> In 2021, Frederiksborg castle is featured in the 5th episode, part 3 of La casa de papel during a heist.

(usually means it was filmed prior to being released, and about a year is an average)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

notes:

https://www.reddit.com/r/LaCasaDePapel/comments/i45lsi/current_filming_location/

https://www.instagram.com/p/CDjE2VIAIK7/

https://www.facebook.com/28085414835/posts/10158544028804836/

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederiksborg_Castle